# List of items not displayed when app loads in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I am a newbie in Angular and Firebase and I am following a tutorial, I created a list of posts, and I have a service who retrieves the full list and then I display it.
My problem is that each time i open the applications, the list of posts is empty, but when I add a new one, it is there !
Here the `PostService`:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Post} from "../models/post.model";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import DataSnapshot = firebase.database.DataSnapshot;

@Injectable()
export class PostService {

  posts: Post[] = [];
  postsSubject = new Subject<Post[]>();

  emitPosts() {
    this.postsSubject.next(this.posts);
  }

  savePosts() {
    firebase.database().ref('/posts').set(this.posts);
  }

  getPosts() {
    firebase.database().ref('/posts')
      .on('value', (data: DataSnapshot) => {
        this.posts = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
      });
  }
}
```

And here my component:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Post} from "../models/post.model";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs/Subscription";
import {PostService} from "../services/post.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {

  posts: Post[];
  postsSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private postService: PostService,
          private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postsSubscription = this.postService.postsSubject.subscribe(
      (posts: Post[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
      }
    );
    this.postService.emitPosts();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.postsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the initial list come from `getPosts()`? If so, I don't see it called anywhere in your code

Comment: that is my problem... in the tutorial he didn't call it anywhere

Comment: Can you try calling `this.postService.getPosts()` in the `ngOnInit`, before `this.postService.emitPosts()`. Also, do you have a link to this tutorial?

Comment: The problem is that the course is in french: https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-avec-angular/creez-une-application-complete-avec-angular-et-firebase

Comment: mmm ok, try and see if calling `getPosts` changes things

Comment: no doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168385/discussion-between-mosch-and-bugs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the asynchronous nature of your operations. You need to modify your `getPosts()` method to notify your component that the list of posts has been retrieved:

```
getPosts() { 
  firebase.database().ref('/posts') 
    .on('value', (data: DataSnapshot) => { 
      this.posts = data.val() ? data.val() : []; 
      this.emitPosts(); 
    }); 
}
```

and the `ngOnInit()` method of your component needs to send the request to firebase to retrieve that list:

```
ngOnInit() { 
  this.postsSubscription = this.postService.postsSubject.subscribe( 
    (posts: Post[]) => { 
      this.posts = posts; 
    } 
  ); 
  this.postService.getPosts(); 
}
```